# simpe php database connetion wont connect database ?

Tags: php

this is my html code

```
<?php include('process.php') ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>

  </head>
  <body>

  <from action="index.php.php" method="post">
  <?php include('errors.php'); ?>

  <lable> name </lable>
  <input  type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter your name"> 


  <lable>location</lable>
  <input  type="text" name="location"  placeholder="enter your location">

  <button type="submit" name="save_btn" >update</button>

  </from>

  </body>
</html>
```

this is my php code

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$name="";
$location="";


// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'newuser', 'password', 'curd');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['save_btn'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
  $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['location']);


    $query = "INSERT INTO data (name, location) VALUES('$name', '$location')";

   mysqli_query($db, $query);


}
```

why its not store in data base?  data base name correct and i have  3 tables

1. id (ai)
2. name (var 200)
3. location (var 200)

in my browser i can locate index.php but when i click button nothing happen any one can explain why its not working?

Comment: You have some important typos, fix them before having a look at the logic please: 
`<from action="index.php.php" method="post">` should be `<form action="index.php" method="post">`

Comment: Can you please var_dump $db? So we can check if DB is connected properly or not.

Comment: `index.php.php`  is the problem  the form submits to a page that does not exist

Comment: check db connect or not `mysqli_connect('localhost', 'newuser', 'password', 'curd') or die('not connect')`

Comment: Too many typos, if you code as you write question titles (without verifying), you can't expect SO to correct that.

Comment: **Error checking** Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @LorenzoS really thz buddy post this as answer i marks as correct <3

Comment: While you're fixing your typos: `<lable>` should be `<label>`. Don't you use and IDE that could/would tell you about those typos?

Comment: This question should be closed as its just about few typos and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine, it seems that the problem is caused by 2 important typos:

`<from action="index.php.php" method="post">` should be `<form action="index.php" method="post">`.

Comment: don't forget the closing form tag `</from>` should also be `</form>`

Comment: We dont normally bother answering a TYPO. We just make a useful comment as you did and vote to close it. TYPO's are of no use to anyone else and the question will soon be deleted anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks, got it